# Am I defining my model parameters correctly when converting from WinBugs to Stan?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, bayesian, stan, winbugs

I'm taking a class and all of the code/modeling examples are done in WinBugs. However, the professor has said that we can use whichever library/language we want when we turn in the homework.

I'm trying to convert the WinBugs examples from class into Stan, but I'm having problems getting my Stan model file correct.

```
model{
    for(i in 1:N){
        y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
         mu[i] <- beta0 + beta1*x[i] 
    }
}

#priors
beta0 ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
beta1 ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)

#prediction
new.x <- 90
ympred <- beta0 + beta1 * new.x
ypred ~ dnorm(ympred, tau)
```

I've come up with the following code for my stan file.

```
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] dependent_variable_y;
    vector[N] independent_variable_x;
}


// these are 
parameters {
  real beta0;
  real beta1;
  real tau;
  real mu;
}

// The model to be estimated. We model the output
// 'y' to be normally distributed with mean 'mu'
// and standard deviation 'sigma'.
model {
  //priors
  beta0 ~ normal(0, 0.001);
  beta1 ~ normal(0, 0.001);
  tau ~ gamma(0.01, 0.01);

  for (i in 1:N){
        mu = beta0 + beta1 * independent_variable_x[i]
        
  }
}
```

The error is currently telling me that I'm missing a } somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Please edit & update your post to include the error you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon in the last relevant line

```
mu = beta0 + beta1 * independent_variable_x[i];
```

That's probably where the missing } is coming from. But more importantly, there's a few mistakes in the model. First, mu is determined completely by the `beta`s and `x`, it's not an independent parameter. Either you put it in the `transformed parameters` block, or just omit saving it altogether. Second, there's no error model. You're not defining how `y` depends on `mu` and `sigma` (assuming `tau` is supposed to be sigma?). Third, (not a mistake, just efficiency) you don't have to loop over `N`, you can just vectorize. Fourth, you're using EXTREMELY narrow priors on the betas, those priors pretty much say that you are sure the betas are 0. You should have a good reason to do so. Assuming you do have that, here's a version that should work:

```
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] y;
    vector[N] x;
}


parameters {
  real beta0;
  real beta1;
  real tau;
}


model {
  //priors
  beta0 ~ normal(0, 0.001);
  beta1 ~ normal(0, 0.001);
  tau ~ gamma(0.01, 0.01);

  y ~ normal(beta0 + beta1 * x, tau);
        
}
```